# jquery - replace row with form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table that is generated by looping through DB entries.  On the row is an edit button.

```
<tr id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
...
<td><button id="editbutton" onClick='edit("<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>","<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>", "<?php echo $camera_quality; ?>", "<?php echo $camera_status; ?>", "<?php echo $email_notice; ?>", "<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>")'>Edit</button></td>
...
</tr>
```

If you click the button it generates a form.  Right now the form is just put below the table.  Here is the edit function:

```
function edit(to, cameraname, cameraquality, camerastatus, emailnotice, camerahash)
{
var mydiv = document.getElementById("editform");
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.method = "post";
myForm.action = to;

//camera name
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.for = "text";
label.innerHTML="Camera name: ";
myForm.appendChild(label);

var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.setAttribute("name", "camera_name"); 
myInput.setAttribute("value", cameraname);
myForm.appendChild(myInput);

//bunch of other code for different parts of the form...

//submit changes button...doesn't do anything yet...
mySubmit = document.createElement("input");
mySubmit.type = "button";
mySubmit.name = "apply_changes";
mySubmit.value = "Apply changes"
myForm.appendChild(mySubmit);

//cancel changes button...doesn't do anything yet...
myCancel = document.createElement("input");
myCancel.type = "button";
myCancel.name = "cancel_changes";
myCancel.value = "Cancel"
myForm.appendChild(myCancel);

mydiv.appendChild(myForm);

}
```

What I want to do is have the row in the table replaced by this form (in some sort of nicely formatted way).  I thought I might be able to use jquery as I do have an id that I loop through for the table row.  For example:

```
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js(document).ready(function(){
  js("#editbutton").click(function(){
  js('#0').hide();
  });
});
```

This shows I can hide the first row by hard coding the first element (#0).  I'm just not sure how to pull in the id based on the edit button row I just selected.  Then change this row to show the form.

Comment: am i right? you want to generate a form of the entire table, or just a row?

Comment: Just a row.  When you click the edit button in the row it opens a form in the row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editbutton').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: closest looks like a great function to use here...but it doesn't work.  For some reason it only hides the first row.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's because I'm telling it to hide the first row ;p  `$(this).closest('tr')` is retrieving the current row that the `#editbutton` is inside of.  Once you have the row you can perform whatever logic you need to against it.

Comment: But from what I understand of closest (which is not much granted) what you gave me should still work for my other rows.  If I click the editbutton in any other row I would have thought it would hide the corresponding row.  But clicking the editbutton on any other row does nothing?

Comment: @TomPepernic could you create a http://jsfiddle.net to show me what problems you're running into.  I could help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: Here it is. Not exactly the same as I have a bunch of php code that generates this but at least has the same behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/h34Hr/ Try clicking the edit buttons for different rows.  Only the first one works.  But still I want to create the form inside the row of the table (wasn't sure how to do that so I just put it in a div at the end)

Comment: @TomPepernic I've updated [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h34Hr/1/).  I've remove the jQuery click event (since you're binding your `edit` function to an onclick property, and move the row selection to the top of the `edit` function.  I've also altered how it pulls the hash values.  Take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes this is great!  Any ideas on how to move the form into the row of the edit button?

Comment: Hrmm, I also don't see understand this syntax: var thisrow = $(t).closest('tr'),
        camerahash = thisrow.prop('data-hash'); is that right?

Comment: Making `thisrow.html(myForm);` the last line of `edit` will put the form inside of the row.  I think at this point you should be well on your way, but I'd like to recommend [jQuery tempates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) since you're currently building the html form from scratch.  Check out the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) for some guidance.